# Determine if rar file is password protected

Tags: javascript, perl, rar

I'd like to be able to determine if the beginning portion (ideally first MB or so) of a file is of a password protected rar file. I don't just need to know if it's a rar file, I need to ensure that the file is password protected.

Is this possible? I know that the rar format is a proprietary format, but is this possible?

Edit:
I'd like to do this by examining the file's content, with either javascript or perl. It should not have access to the rar library.

Edit2:
With at least some consistency so far, I have been able to determine that the 10th byte appears to be always set to zero if no encryption is enabled. I haven't done enough testing yet to confirm this works reliably yet, but nonetheless, that is the result I am seeing.

Comment: Half an answer: libmagic 5.08 does not help distinguish password-protected archives, perhaps [file a bug](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/)? The RAR header is documented at http://kthoom.googlecode.com/hg/docs/unrar.html, happy hacking

Comment: Thank you for digging up the documentation for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experiments gave me the following subroutine:

```
sub is_rarfile_protected {
   my ($rar_filename) = @_;
   open my $rar_fh, '<', $rar_filename or die $!, "\n";
   sysread $rar_fh, my $mark, 25;
   return ord (substr $mark, -1) & 0b100; 
}
```

... which works for me so far.

Sadly, I don't have Rar installed, so I cannot check whether it'll work on all the password-encrypted rar-files (including multi-volumes, etc.) or not.

Comment: I tested it on about 5 different rar files, and it gave inconsistent results.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about there results?

Comment: 2 of the files I've encrypted (with encrypt file listing enabled) return a 0, one returns a 4. It does seem to consistently return a 4 for files with encryption (but encrypt listing disabled).

Comment: Argh. Is that possible for you to share the file with encrypt file listing enabled?

Comment: You know, I think I got it worked out. Your method works flawlessly if the files themselves are encrypted, and a little less than half the time if the listing is also encrypted. Consistently the hex of the 10th byte will be set (non-zero) if the entire thing is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

[You could always try this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=824309)

For those who can't perlmonks:

> Re: Determine if a file is password protected
>
> by rubasov:
>
> If you don't want to implement the file format specific test for each of your extensions, then you can peek in the randomness of your data. Any well designed encryption scheme will result random looking encrypted data (to resist statistical analysis). But if the encryption is poorly designed this won't be much help for you.
>
> Beware that this approach has serious caveats: if your data can be real/pseudo random or compressed data, then it will also look like than a pile of random bits, so for example you won't be able to distinguish between a simple and an encrypted rar/zip file. (And don't forget that simple looking document formats can use compression internally.)
>
> For the concrete implementation search for the chi square test on CPAN (I haven't looked but I'm almost sure you'll find some implementation) and try to experiment with it whether it can be good enough for your purpose.

Comment: Since RAR is indeed a compressed format, this approach is doomed to fail.